# Partition Table Entries is not in disk order

Tags: filesystems, partition, devices

How bad is the effect of Partition Table Entries is not in disk order, will it just like nothing so won't need any fix ?

Answer (score 5):

Correct, there is nothing to worry about. Depending on which software you use to look at the table **you** might be confused about the layout but the computer will not.

Answer (score 2):

This is the number one hit from Google for

> Partition table entries are not in disk order

so I think it is important to log this answer, instead of relying on manually edit the `sfdisk` output and manually use the `sfdisk` again to fix it.

It is very easy to fix partition name ordering with that most feared and deadly disk management tool called `fdisk`. Here is the summary. For details, see for e.g., [here](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=cfc1e8bd-8d9b-4c68-b111-bef103d4dd3e#gsc.tab=0).

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

- enter `x` to enter expert mode
- enter `f` to fix partition order
- enter `r` to return to main menu
- enter `w` to write the partition table changes to disk

### Remember that `grub` needs to be reinstalled after this.

I just rebooted into `grub` rescue, so I had to reinstall `grub`.

Comment: This is the first hit _for you_. Remember that Google results are tailored to the user. However, since this  question was asked a long time ago by a user who has since left the site, it would be better to ask a new question and then post this as an answer instead of putting a new question into the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it depends on the case but usually, as long as the partitions don't have any corruption on the data related to them at the partition table, the system may be able to read them with no hassle. Take a Windows **dynamic disk** partition as example, it can start at position 0 of disk, go up to 10GB, then jump to 20GB and end at 30GB. It will have 20GB in total, [0GB-10GB] + [20GB-30GB], that's what the system will tell you. It will take care of all the physical management of the data you put inside the partition.

For example, at my gaming PC I made my 500GB HDD a **dynamic disk** in order to create more than 4 primary partitions. The objective is to reduce **disk seeking** (game data that is too far from one another) and **fragmentation** (many small files that get R/W every time). I know there are many other ways to do it, like making the disk GPT or creating a big extended partition and fill it with logical partitions, but this approach worked fine until now.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to worry about but that might be confusing and lead to data loss in case you're editing the partition table directly, e.g. if you're using `fdisk`, `gdisk` and similar utilities.

I normally solve this issue by using sfdisk (boot from a LiveCD/USB drive):

```
sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sda.table
# Correct the order, it's pretty straitforward
vi sda.table
sfdisk /dev/sda < sda.table
reboot
```

And reboot.